# Delete TextContents of XML element before appending text

Tags: java, xml, domparser

I am appending text to XML element iteratively like the following

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setValidating(false);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("./myXML.xml")));
        Element element =  doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList node1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
        Element fn= (Element) node1.item(0);
        Text text = doc.createTextNode(Content);
        fn.appendChild(text);
        printtoXML(doc);
```

My printXML method is updating xml by using TransformerFactory
fn.setTextContent() method does not work here,Because in every iteration it setting old text to new text.
I want to append Text iteratively, and in my next execution i want to delete old text contents of the particular element and append it again.
I have to execute the program many times for my testing and i don't want to append the same text again and again....

Could you please help me to solve this problem..

Answer (score 0):

this might work

```
    Text text;
    void callsomefunctionthousendtimes(){
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("./myXML.xml")));
    text = doc.createTextNode("");
    Element element =  doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList node1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
    Element fn= (Element) node1.item(0);
    //TODO call your functionName(content) 1000 times here
    fn.appendChild(text);
    printtoXML(doc);
    }

    void functionName(String content){
    text = text.replaceWholeText(text.getWholeText() + content);
    }
```

added bonusus, only load the doc in once

Comment: It works same as setTextContent() method.At the end it prints only last record of my text.

Comment: oh sorry, i understood your question wrong, its kind of hard to grasp, can you explain "I want to append Text iteratively, and in my next execution i want to delete old text contents of the particular element and append it again" a bit better?

Comment: One execution of my program contains some 1000 iterations,so one execution appends 1000 lines of text to my XML.In my next execution of program i would like to delete text contents of particular xml element and append the text again.

Comment: hope ths is what you were looking for